# What is null ? doing in this line of JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have this line of code in JS for handing payments, but I'm not sure what it's  doing as I've never seen some of this syntactic sugar before.

```
var fund = response.card != null ? response.card[0] : response.bank_acct[0];
```

Comment: what "syntactic sugar" do you mean?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:

Comment: It's the same "syntactic sugar" as in C, PHP, Perl, and a number of other languages.

Comment: @Barmar: Indeed, or any other language [syntactically derived from B](http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/dmr/kbman.html). :-) (Warning: Link is PDF to B manual.)

Comment: It does what the basic language syntax definition says it does. Look up the `?` operator. Also, please give your question a meaningful title, such as "What does the ? operator do in JavaScript?".

Comment: @T.J.Crowder wow *dated January 7, 1972* :d

Comment: @1nflktd: Yup. I'm not sure BCPL (B's ancestor) didn't have it, but I'm not sure it *did*, either. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the conditional operator. Instead of writing this:

```
var fund;
if(response.card != null )
{
    fund = response.card[0]
}
else
{
    fund = response.bank_acct[0];
}
```

you could write this:

```
var fund = response.card != null ? response.card[0] : response.bank_acct[0];
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with your answer per se, but I question encouraging the use of SO as a Q&A resource for people who have not bothered to learn the basic syntax of the language. You also could have pointed him to authoritative pages about `?`, and/or given suggestions to him about how to find such resources on his own, so he doesn't have to post to SO every time he sees a syntactic construct he doesn't know, and/or commented on its long history in other programming languages, and/or commented on why one form might be preferred to the other in what kinds of cases.

Answer (score 3):

It works the same as ([and is considered shorthand for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)) this conditional statement:

```
var fund;
if (response.card != null) {
  fund = response.card[0];
} else {
  fund = response.bank_acct[0];
}
```

Comment: your triple equals should be assignments, shouldn't they?

Comment: End of a long day. Thanks for the catch.